# WordPress 4.4.1 Broken Shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

after updating WordPress to 4.4.1(Hosting provider did automatically,meh!), my ShortCode plugins, for example, YouTube, is broken and printing out the ShortCode only, i.e, [youtube 1233456], where the numbers are the ID of the video. I did some research and this looks to be related to spaces [reference here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-broken-with-wp-44-upgrade#post-7792572).
Problem is I have like a thousand posts to go back and fix this for. I was thinking of running a preg_replace function the replace the space character, however, am not having much luck. See below. Is there a better way to do this? Here is the function I am trying to fix.

```
add_shortcode('youtube','youtube_video'); 

function youtube_video($attr) { 
$output = '<div class="youtube-container"><iframe width="560" height="420" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $attr[0] . '?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe></div>'; 
return $output;
}
```

I was trying to do something like this, but no luck

```
function youtube_video($attr) { 
$output = '<div class="youtube-container"><iframe width="560" height="420" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $attr[0] . '?autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false"></iframe></div>'; 

return preg_replace('/\s.*$/', "", $output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be how you're calling the short code. see https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/23/changes-to-the-shortcode-api/. For example, this used to be allowed:

```
<a href="/[shortcode query="?ref="]">
```

But, now it's not allowed. The problem is the un-escaped double quote which apparently was causing a cross-site scripting vulnerability. Here is how you would fix it:

```
Example 1: <a href="/[shortcode query='?ref=']">
Example 2: <a href='/[shortcode query="?ref="]'>
```

Either example will work.

Here's another example. This is no longer allowed:

```
<div style="background-image: url('[shortcode]');">
```

Here's how they suggest doing it:

```
<div [shortcode]>
```